# Pushing water along is it possible to calculate the angle it forms

Tags: gravity, fluid-dynamics

If I had a static thin (a few mm) film of water lying on a surface and I tried to push a squeegee across the surface in order to move the water. Would the water rise up in front of the squeegee? Would the angle be possible to calculate if the speed were to increase and or the force of gravity were to increase?

Comment: check out "shallow water equation" on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_water_equations

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can approximate the water in front of the wiper as being contained in a box being subjected to the given accellerations. The steady state angle of the surface will be perpendicular to the vector formed by the the gravity accelleration vector *minus* the  lateral accelleration vector (i.e., water surface is normal to the net force).

E.g., Accelleration  = 10 m/s to the right, g=10 m$s^2$, so the resulting water surface will be perpendicular to the vector: $\langle -10, -9.81\rangle$

You can derive this intuitively by noting that $\frac{dh}{dx} = \frac{-a}{g}$ since its the differential pressure between the infinitesimal vertal water slices that is actually applying the force to the water, allowing it to accelerate. Since it is uniformly accellerating, the *difference* in heights must be the same for each differential slice of water.